# Active-Directory blocks LDAP connections from other hosts

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, ldap

I am trying to connect to Active-Directory using LDAP protocol. If the host is "localhost", then there is no problem. If I change the host to anything else, the server responds with wrong user/pass.
I have tried changing the "username" to user@domain, DOMAIN\user...
thanks.

(OS: win server 2012)

[Screetshot explaining everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMH5j.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the server name (example: SERVER.DOMAIN.COM), instead of the ip directly fixed the problem.

That means the dns is required.